# How to define the default quicklook viewer

Tags: quicklook

How does one define the default quicklook viewer for files which don't already have one.

For instance I would like to define textview as my default quicklook viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually came across this project [ql-plaintext](https://github.com/bigkm/qlplaintext)

It pretty much does what I was looking for, I can now open shell scripts with QuickLook